# serving XMLHttp POST request on node js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, xmlhttprequest

Im trying to serve XMLHttprequest (POST) on node js server.

Server side:

```
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());


    app.post('/count', function(request, response){
      console.log(request.body);      
      response.send(request.body);    
    });
```

Client side:

```
<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var resp = ""
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        resp = xmlhttp.responseText;
        resp = JSON.parse(resp);
        document.write(resp);
        }
}

var check = "Hello";

function show(){
xmlhttp.open("POST","http://localhost:3000/count",  true);
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(check));
</script>
```

The output Im getting is   [object Object]

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Try `JSON.stringify(request.body).forEach(console.log)` and see what it prints.

Might make your code easier to reason with if you use the `fetch` API on the clientside: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: There's no reason to keep stringifying. I don't know where people are getting this from.

Comment: For starters, replace `document.write(resp)` with `console.log(resp)`. What you do see in the browser's console?

Comment: **Object {} __proto__: Object**  (after replacing with console.log(resp)  )

Answer (score 1):

addition of setrequestheader on client side solved the issue.

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```